# Computing $\int_0^t B^n (s) \, dB(s)$ (stochastic integral)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion and $t>0$.

It can easily be shown that $$\int_0^t B(s) dB(s) = \frac{B^2(t) - t}{2}$$ using integration by parts formula.

Do we have such analytic form for $$\int_0^t B^n(s) dB(s)$$

for all $n \in \mathbb N$ ? Or at least for some $n$ ? Like $n=2$ or $n=3$ ?

Comment: Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Use Ito's lemma for $B^{n+1}(t)$, where $B=(B(t))_{t \geq 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion. Then for $n\geq 1$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
dB^{n+1}(t) = (n+1)B^{n}(t)dB(t) + \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)B^{n-1}dt
\end{align*}
and so after rearranging 
$$ \int_0^tB^n(s)dB(s) = \frac{1}{n+1}B^{n+1}(t) -\frac{1}{2}n \int_0^t B^{n-1}(s)ds .$$ Is that what you wanted?

Comment: What I want, if possible, is to have an expression with no integral. So actually compute the integral just like in the case $n=1$

Comment: @W.Volante But you can iteratively use the formula that m_gnacik obtained to get your expressions without the integrals for every $n$. So aren't you satisfied?

Comment: No, because we do not know what's $\int_0^t B(s) \, ds$.